# RCS Business Messaging API. User initated conversations

Tags: google-api, rich-communications-services

With RCS Business Messaging API, I understand that I can send messages via API, and that I can answer users messages.

But can a user initiate a new conversation, with a business that use RCS Business Messaging API to answer?

And if yes, how can a user do that (via a phone number or a link) ?